# getting the user's server profile banner in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

Im working on `!avatar` and `!banner` commands. I know i can get the users guild avatar (server profile) by using `member.display_avatar` and im trying to get the users guild banner (server profile) but there is no `"member.display_banner"` or something so my Question is is it possible to get the users guild banner?

This is how i get the normal banner:

```py
@commands.command(aliases=["bn"])
    async def banner(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
        if member is None:
            member = ctx.author

        user = await self.bot.fetch_user(member.id)

        if user.banner is None:
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
                description="this user has no banner."
            ))
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                description=f"{user.banner.url}"
            )
            embed.set_image(url=user.banner.url)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Using `fetch` might be the opposite of what you want. Try using `get_user` and using the cached banner asset.

Answer (score 1):

banners are actually weird you have to request them from discords API. I don't know why.

here is a snippet of code I used previously using requests.

````
req = await self.client.http.request(discord.http.Route("GET","/users/{uid}",uid=member.id))
banner_id = req["banner"]
if banner_id:
     banner_url = f"<https://cdn.discordapp.com/banners/{member.id}/{banner_id}?size=1024>"```

EDIT:
This was the case previously but you can actually get them using the code above from poster.
````

Comment: He's already using `user.banner` in the codeblock in his post so I'm quite sure he's aware that that exists.

Comment: ahhh yes i see. ill edit my answer

Comment: i mean yea that gives me the banner url but im trying to get the GUILD banner url...

Comment: ahh. yea I don't know of a current way if there is any to do that.